# Como renombrar valor de keys de un objeto

Tags: javascript, web

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
   [
  {
    "U_Subrubros": "00000189",
    "MontoVenta": 5336946.78,
    "Cantidad": 1495
  },
  {
    "U_Subrubros": "00000124",
    "MontoVenta": 1117355.33,
    "Cantidad": 169
  },
  {
    "U_Subrubros": "00000611",
    "MontoVenta": 1045471.46,
    "Cantidad": 454
  }
]
```

Existe alguna forma de cambiarle el nombre al valor de la key U_Subrubros? Por ejemplo la que se llama U_Subrubros: 00000189 me gustaría que se llame U_Subrubros: COMBOS. Alguna forma de hacerlo con javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Un método bastante sencillo para hacerlo es así (es lo que utilizo yo):

```js
function renameProp(obj, keyToRemove, newKey) {
  // Verificas si la propiedad existe y si el nuevo nombre es distinto
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(keyToRemove) && keyToRemove !== newKey) {
    // Defines la nueva propiedad, tomando como base la anterior (incluso si es un objeto)
    Object.defineProperty(obj, newKey, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, keyToRemove));
    // Eliminas la propiedad anterior
    delete obj[keyToRemove];
  }
}
```

Lo utilizas tal que así:

```js
let myObj = { "prop1": "myVal" };
renameProp(myObj, "prop1", "value"); // Cambia la propiedad "prop1" a "value".
console.log(myObj); // { value: "myVal" }
```

```js
function renameProp(obj, keyToRemove, newKey) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(keyToRemove) && keyToRemove !== newKey) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, newKey, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, keyToRemove));
    delete obj[keyToRemove];
  }
}

let myObj = { "prop1": "myVal" };
console.log("Antes del cambio:", myObj);
renameProp(myObj, "prop1", "value");
console.log("Después del cambio:", myObj);
```

Comment: Gracias me funciona de esta forma. Pero al querer hacerle un .map a myObj me devuelve un error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: myObj.map is not a function" Por que puede ser?